# How to get rid of padding when search bar is open

Tags: css

All my code is placed in a header with class 'example'. When 'search' button is pressed, div with class 'search-bar' appears and have its borders identical to those of header. However, I would like to see search-bar bump into the left edge of the screen. How can it be achieved?

```js
const searchBar =
  document.querySelector('#search-bar');
const openBtn = document.querySelector('#open-btn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close-btn');
const brand = document.querySelector('#brand');

openBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleSlider());
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleSlider());

function toggleSlider() {
  searchBar.classList.toggle('open');
  brand.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.example {
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.brand {
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.brand.open {
  color: #fff;
}

.slide-area {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.search-bar.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<header class="example">
  <div class="slide-area">
    <div id="brand" class="brand">Menu Stuff
    </div>
    <button id="open-btn">Search
            </button>
    <div id="search-bar" class="search-bar">
      <button id="close-btn">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">Log in</div>
</header>
```

[Link to the working example in CodePen](https://codepen.io/Giulia_Marla/pen/ZEJJPBO)

Comment: I think you should post an image showing the desired effect. From the question it is unclear what is the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

Just change `overflow: hidden` from `.slide-area` to `.example`

```js
const searchBar =
  document.querySelector('#search-bar');
const openBtn = document.querySelector('#open-btn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close-btn');
const brand = document.querySelector('#brand');

openBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleSlider());
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleSlider());

function toggleSlider() {
  searchBar.classList.toggle('open');
  brand.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.example {
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.brand {
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.brand.open {
  color: #fff;
}

.slide-area {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
}

.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.search-bar.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<header class="example">
  <div class="slide-area">
    <div id="brand" class="brand">Menu Stuff
    </div>
    <button id="open-btn">Search
            </button>
    <div id="search-bar" class="search-bar">
      <button id="close-btn">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">Log in</div>
</header>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/OguzhanUlukaya/pen/bGrrJpe?editors=1100)

Comment: Can you explain what changes you have done and why?

Comment: @kiner_shah just changed `overflow: hidden` from `.slide-area` to `.example`

Comment: @Oguz3 Slider should appear not from the very right edge of the screen, but as you see in my example. The padding of the component should remain intact, while search bar should take up padding only on the left side.

Comment: Code-only answers are almost never good answers. Yours is no exception.